# VDDK API Mocking

Tags: vmware, vmware-sdk

We are using VDDK apis in our backend and require to mock the VDDK APIs for testing. As it is not a SOAP interface, would anyone know the protocol for used to help us mock the apis?

Answer (score 0):

this is not a full answer, because I am working on it right now, but the protocol seems to be FTP based. Here are the first lines (S> means server answer, C> means client request):

```
C> (client connects on port 902)
S> 220 (something)
C> (if server answer contains "SSL Required", then switch to SSL)
C> USER user
S> 331 Password required for user.
C> PASS password
S> 230 User user logged in.
```

The next steps I'll follow is to write a dummy FTP server and see what the C client library sends to the server.

To be continued... Maybe :)